# Model set fields in Django

Tags: python, database, django

I have a Django model that needs to represent a set of data. What is the canonical way to implement this? I don't see a models.SetField() in the documentation. I could use a text field and pickling.

I recognize that this isn't the fastest way to do it, but this part of the code doesn't need to be super fast - simplicity is better at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but it seems to me your looking for some getter/setter functionality that automatically pickles the values:

```
import cPickle
class MyModel(models.Model):
    cpickled_values = models.TextField()

    def get_values(self):
        return cPickle.loads(str(self.cpickled_values))

    def set_values(self, value):
        self.cpickled_value = cPickle.dumps(values)

    values = property(get_values, set_values)
```

You can then do something like `obj.values = {'item1': data1}` and your data will be pickeld automatically.

Comment: Acutally I just had another look on this, and there are also snippets that offer you a `PickeledField` that already includes the same funcitonality as above: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1694/